# Saving a HASH to Redis on a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redis

Im just starting off with Redis with Rails so this maybe a dumb question.

I am trying to save a hash to redis server but when I retrieve it its just a string IE.

```
hash = {"field" => "value", "field2" => "value2"}
$redis.set('data', hash)

#So collecting the data
@data = $redis.get('data')
```

This is obviously wrong as its returning as a string.

I have also tried looping some results and using the hset ie.

```
@data.each do |d|
  $redis.hset('data', d.field, d.value)
end

# errror
# ERR Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
```

Not sure where to go. I have deleted the key $redis.del('data') to make sure that was not the issue.

Hope you can advise, Lee

Comment: The poster seems to want a ruby dict stored as a serialized string, but I get the same error when doing hset even though the key is a hash. Can anyone guess why that might be?

Comment: Figured it out! It wasn't that I was doing an HSET on a string, it was that I was then doing a GET on a hash when I should have been using HGETALL.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I should have read the redis docs more thorough.

Answer:

```
IN
$redis.set 'data', hash.to_json

OUT
data = JSON.parse($redis.get("data"))
```

Comment: That's fine if what you want to do is store a serialized hash, but I actually want a redis hash, and I'm getting this error as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the solution. I didn't read the redis docs carefully, too. This solution can be use for all kinds of ruby object also. [redis doc](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/master/README.md#storing-objects)

Answer (score 50):

The redis gem will remap your hash like this:

```
$redis.mapped_hmset "test", { foo: "bar" }
$redis.hgetall "test" => {"foo"=>"bar"}
```

Comment: Just be careful, inner hashes get returned as strings.

Storing `{:a => 1, :b => {:c => 2}}` gets returned as `{"a"=>"1", "b"=>"{:c=>2}"}`

Also, you lose symbolized keys.

Comment: A little late to the party, but using `transform_keys` or `deep_symbolize_keys` you can turn those de-symbolized keys back into symbolized.

Comment: Just be careful, hash does not overwrites, but merges if exist, so 

```[1] pry(main)> RedisClient.mapped_hmset(:test, {foo: 'bar'})
=> "OK"```
```[2] pry(main)> RedisClient.mapped_hmset(:test, {bar: 'foo'})
=> "OK"```
```[3] pry(main)> RedisClient.hgetall(:test)
=> {"foo"=>"bar", "bar"=>"foo"}```

Answer (score 12):

In order to save a hash in redis. You must pass the key as a first parameter and then the next parameters must be the keys and values on `hmset` method.

```
$redis.hmset('user:007', :name, 'Antonio', :busy, 'maybe', :ping, 'pong')
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: How to set TTL for hmset?

Comment: Like this?

```hash = { name: 'Antonio', busy: 'maybe', ping: 'pong' }
$redis.hmset('user:007', *hash)```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$redis.set('data', hash)` you actually saving a regular Redis string, even though you use an hash variable (it might be serialized to Json string, but I'm really not sure about it).

Try using `$redis.hset('data', hash)` (not by looping through the fields as you did).

Another point: Are you sure you've deleted the previous key entirely? Did you try to `hset` a completely different key to eliminate the option the previous string key is still "out there"?

Comment: $redis.hset('data', hash), gives me error:  wrong number of arguments (2 for 3).  hset sets them individual. I also tried $redis.hmset('data', hash) and got error: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hmset' command