# Store complex objects in redis or memcached (ruby)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, redis, memcached

is it possible to store complex objects (i.e. ActiveRecords) a database like redis or memcached without the need to perform a YAML::load / YAML::dump ?

What i am looking for is something like a global var which
a) is shared between threads
b) is not flushed when restarting my webserver (this is optional)

The thing a want to do is creating a cache which stores the results of several methods. Currently im using a $global var, but im concerned about what happens when using a multi-threaded webserver.

The code for this project can be found here:

https://github.com/florianeck/3d_cache/blob/master/lib/three_d/class_method_cache.rb

I'm happy about every advice!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving a HASH to Redis on a rails app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832124/saving-a-hash-to-redis-on-a-rails-app)

Comment: no, its not... i dont have problem with hashes arrays etc... im talking about storing an array with e.g. 600 ActiceRecord Objects...

If to a YAML::dump/YAML::load with it, performance is terrible... no benfit for me when trying to speed things up by caching this data

Comment: You will need to serialize the array, are those `YAML` methods the way to do so in Ruby ? Or you can revise your code and make good use of Redis structures.

Comment: Refactoring is way to expensive in this case.... :-(

Comment: The more common method of dealing with this type of problem is to use page or fragment caching. I didn't look through the project, if you are using the output to derive something else it may not easily work for you - http://signalvnoise.com/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works

Answer (score 2):

i tried dumpig data with Marshal instead of YAML, which produces a performance i can deal with, so i'll try Marshal + Redis to solve this problem!